# Django post_delete: count all objects which have one matching attribute with deleted object

Tags: python, django, filter, count, signals

I have a custom function which is called when deleting an object of the Model Orders, I use post_delete for this.

An instance of the model "Orders" always have the ForeignKey "user". When deleting an object of the model "Orders", I want to check whether there are other instances of the model "Orders" with the same "user".

```
def delete_reverse(sender, **kwargs):
try:
    if Orders.objects.filter(user__equal=kwargs['instance'].user).count() == 1:
        kwargs['instance'].user.delete()
    else:
        ...         
except:
    pass
post_delete.connect(delete_reverse, sender=Orders)
```

Unfortunately, the if condition is not working, i.e. it is not true even when the count of according entries should be 1. Do you see any issue with my count() function?

Comment: Do not use a *blanket* `except`. Please remove it and look if it raises an exception. I have the idea that the `__equal` does *not* exists.

Comment: Furthermore I find the logic rather strange. `post_delete` means that at *that* moment, the `Order` is already removed, so then the count is zero (given there are no other orders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are some problems with this code:

1. You seem to make use of an **`__equal`** field lookup, but this lookup does *not* exists in the list of [standard field lookups [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups), the closest is `__exact`, but it is probably not necessary here;
2. you use a "*blanket exception*" (!), this is a severe *anti-pattern*: if something fails, then you will never get informed about that. Like the *Zen of Python* says: *never pass exceptions silently, unless silenced explicitly*.
3. A post-delete means that the delete already took place, hence at that moment, the instance is no longer in the database, as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-delete):

   > Note that the object will no longer be in the database, so be very careful what you do with this instance.

The last item thus means that you probably want to check if the count is zero (hence that no `Order` with that `user_id` exists anymore):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Orders)
def delete_reverse(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not Order.objects.filter(user_id=instance.user_id).exists():
        instance.user.delete()
```

Note however that even by doing this, there are still scenario's where the database can contain `User`s without any `Order`s: for example when we change the `user_id` of an `Order`, then it is possible that the previous user no longer has anymore, but this function will not get triggered. So it might be worth to *periodically* check the database for such cases.

Furthermore I do not know if removing the `User` is a good idea anyway. If this is the authentication model in Django it can result in the fact that the admin user is removed if for example by accident an order was put on their name and that order is removed later. Furthermore removing a user can result in a large cascade of removals (of all kinds of "entities" in which that user is involved).

> **Note**: a Django model normally has a *singular* name, so I adivce, like I did in the answer, to rename the `Orders` model to `Order`.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer, works great!

Users have to be deleted due to privacy policy in our case :)

Comment: @schlaumi2001: well I think it might be better to have some kind of flag that prevents certain users from getting deleted (for example admin users, staff, etc.)